# What steps are needed to make this abstract?

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I am learning .NET Core Web API. I have a model class like this:

```
namespace Game.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int GameId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string [] Options { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The thing is I have a game that has multiple answers so I'll need

```
public string[] Answer { get; set; }
```

How can I create this behaviour in my game class? ^

I thought about this:

```
public class Answers
{
    private string ans;
    private string[] anss;

    public Answers(string answer)
    {
       ans = answer
    }

    public Answers(string [] answers)
    {
       anss = answers
    }
}
```

I thought about using an interface, but I don't think that's the use case here. I am trying to tie everything up into a knot to understand this. I would be grateful for anybody's help with this.

Comment: What does the code using the model look like? How does it differ between single and multiple answer games? Have you considered simply modelling a single-answer game with an array of length 1?

Comment: Surely it is a *Question* that has an *Answer*, not a Game

Comment: Do not name classes in the plural. Your Answer class should be singular and if you represent multiple answers in some object, you have eg `public List<Answer> Answers {get;set;}`. If you're making a multi choice Question that has a collection of N number of Answer, you can also have a single Answer property that tracks the correct Answer.

Comment: At some point your game will have a collection of  `Player` s that have a collection of  QuestionAnswer pairings - every player reads a question and decided an answer - you thus track the question:answer given by each player on a per player basis and you can work out if they're right or not by comparing the player's question-answer Answer to the question's CorrectAnswer answer

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for the input, im really grateful. If i understand correctly, I should have a property called IsMultiAnswer of type boolean, a property called List<answer> answers and another property called Answer theAnswer(for one answer, questions) ?

Or should the isMultiAnswer be used as the check like 
if(isMultiAnswer==true) // use answers else use theAnswer

i was thinking of doing that, with the array on the length of the array

so for example, if array.length>1, then ill know that this is a multi answer question.

Comment: @CaiusJard i wanted to dive deeper into OOP and find a way to have a property called answers, and it could either be an array or a string, so i thought that if i initialised it in a constructor and then wrote my getters and setters in the answers class, would that be suffice from an engineering stand point?


Also thanks for the tip about answers being singular, this is the second time someone has to tell me to follow proper naming convention xD

Comment: It all depends on what you're modelling, and its why you can't ask the questions like it here - SO annot answer questions where the response is one person's opinion of how it should be designed. For me, I can't understand why the Game only has one question. For me a game like trivia, or a social quiz, a gameshow is one game (or one round/episode) that has many questions, and each question has many answers.. It might even be that multiple answers are correct. and if that's the case you could model Game -> List<Question>, Question -> List<Answer>, Answer.IsCorrect.. If a Player has..

Comment: ..a Question that they can give multiple answers to (e.g. "Give 2 answers from these 6") then you're looking at QuestionAnswerCollection having a link to a Question, and a collection of Answer that the player gave, and you're testing if All the Answer are correct. If it's not a multi choice question, maybe it has only one correct answer - you can put just one answer in the list of Answer the questions has... For me the biggest thing about this exercise in terms of your mental modelling is not the finer points of is multi, is single, but how should Game/ Player / Question / Answer link up

Comment: *if array.length>1, then ill know that this is a multi answer question* - that seems acceptable to me, because if you have a Question, and it can support N answers, and M of those are correct, and a player can win a point by getting X/N correct it should work for everything from "In Jan 2022 who was the President of the USA?" -> 1 question, 1 answer in its answers list, players must exactly type Joe Biden.. To "Pick 3 cities in Europe from this list of 50 city names" -> 1 question 50 answers of cities all over the world, 10 are from Europe and hence correct, Player has to get 3 of them..

Comment: How you treat those answers is different - in one, you're showing the user the multi choices and putting a checkbox, so they can't spell it wrong. In the other you're taking their typing, making it an answer, searching the answers list for it.. But youre storing the data in the same way. Really note the object graph here - Question is more than "just a string" because I'm saying it has a list of 1 or more Answer. I'm saying Answer is more than "just a string" because it might have a "is correct" flag for those rounds where you want to baffle users by showing them *wrong* answers.. This is a..

Comment: ..departure from the earlier situation I was describing where the Question had a list of N answers and tracked which *one* was correct, because that limited the scenario to questions only having *one* answer. If you know there will only ever be one correct answer to a question, that's fine. If you don't know or know there will be more, you have to model for that. Everything in software engineering is a judgement of how to model what you model to get the job done for the spec you know and can foresee. You might know it'll be 5 years before you release "more than one correct answer" feature

Comment: *i wanted to dive deeper into OOP and find a way to have a property called answers, and it could either be an array or a string* - deeper OOP would, for me, be about getting you to see if there is anything else beyond "it's just a string" that is *worth* modelling about "an answer" - how about "is it actually correct?" or "how many people said it?" if you're making a "we asked 100 people to name a brand of car.." style game. The answer is one thing, but you need other info to have the game rules work - Bob says Ford, 32 people said that. Did more people say Tesla? Now, you can sure say..

Comment: .."ok, i'll have an array of string Questions, and array of string Answers, and an array of int HowManySaidThat, and then a rule of 'the question at array slot 0 is answered by answer slot 0 and how many said is at HowMany slot 0..." but that's really not an OOP way of looking at the world, to throw all your data in N arrays and "this data is related to that data by the same position in each different array". Instead we're about building hierarchies of objects, classifying things in ways such that all X's relevant, related properties are kept together.

Comment: @CaiusJard God Bless you, you explain things poetically. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is not of technical nature but more of structural one.
If I understood correctly you want to have two types of game:

1. Single answer game
2. Multiple answer game

So with that having in mind you could create Enum, something like this:

```
public enum GameType
{
    SingleAnswer,
    MultipleAnswer
}
```

Regarding that what I would suggest is that you can model using standard **OneToMany** relationship with **Game being principal entity** and **Answer being dependent entity**.

*Disclaimer i will use List in example but can be easily replaced with arrays depending on use-case.*

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<string> Options { get; set; }

    public GameType Type { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
  
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int GameId { get; set; }
}
```

So in validation logic of adding answer/s to game you could use `GameType` as parameter of validity and max number of possible answers that can be linked to single game.

Comment: Be careful answering opinion based questions; it is difficult for an answer to be objectively correct in these scenarios. The enum and the answer.gameid seem unnecessary to me

Comment: Hi Dejus, thanks for the input, i will review of its a working scenario.